# Dataframe select all the empty rows that are there for a particular column using the current column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

have a df with values

```
a                                b 

2010-01-04 05:05:31.657        NaT
NaT                            NaT
2019-01-04 05:06:31.857       2010-01-04 01:02:03.657
2019-01-04 05:09:46.963        NaT
```

Get all the data where `a` should have no null values and b should have empty rows(NaT)

Required Output:

```
a                                b 

2010-01-04 05:05:31.657        NaT
2019-01-04 05:09:46.963        NaT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with chained conditions by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and 
[`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
df1 = df[df["a"].notna() & df["b"].isna()]
print (df1)
                        a   b
0 2010-01-04 05:05:31.657 NaT
3 2019-01-04 05:09:46.963 NaT
```